# How to fully/correctly exit a Qt program from the main form?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm writing a Qt program (using Qt 5.4) that reads frames from a webcam based on a QTimer, not a separate thread (interval set to 20 ms, of course it takes much longer than 1/50 of a second to read a frame from the webcam and process it, I'd approximate the frame rate is perhaps 20 fps.  Anyhow, the function which runs when the timer cycles is a slot and is as follows:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void frmMain::processFrameAndUpdateGUI() {

bool blnFrameReadSuccessfully = capWebcam.read(matOriginal);      // get next frame from the webcam

if (!blnFrameReadSuccessfully || matOriginal.empty()) {           // if we did not get a frame
    QMessageBox::information(this, "", "unable to read from webcam \n\n exiting program\n");
    QApplication::quit();
}

// process frame here . . .
```

The idea being if the webcam can be successfully read at the beginning of the program, but then cannot be (webcam stops working, user accidentally disconnects webcam, etc.) the program should show a message box to this effect and then close itself entirely.

With the above, if I unplug the webcam while the program is running for testing purposes, the message box appears as intended, but after choosing OK, a debug error screen appears.  If I choose "Abort" the form is still there and will not respond.  After attempting to close the form multiple times Windows asks "the program does not seem to be responding, would you like to close?" at which time I can close the form.  Clearly this is not achieving the intended effect.

After various Googling I found the suggestion to modify as follows:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void frmMain::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *) {
    QApplication::quit();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void frmMain::processFrameAndUpdateGUI() {

bool blnFrameReadSuccessfully = capWebcam.read(matOriginal);      // get next frame from the webcam

if (!blnFrameReadSuccessfully || matOriginal.empty()) {           // if we did not get a frame
    QMessageBox::information(this, "", "unable to read from webcam \n\n exiting program\n");
    closeEvent(new QCloseEvent());
}

// process frame here . . .
```

When I first saw this code I was optimistic, however it gives me the same result as above (program hangs with the form still open).  I'm using OpenCV 2.4.11 for my image processing and my program has 4 files:

- frmmain.h (.h for the main form, which is a standard QMainWindow made with Qt Creator)
- frmmain.cpp (.cpp for the main form, where the above code resides)
- main.cpp (which I have not changed from how Qt Creator made it)
- frmmain.ui (typical form with a small number of common widgets added via Qt Creator)

Yes, I realize that I could show an error message on one of the widgets that can show text, return from the function, and leave it to the user to close the program, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.  Can anybody offer further advice as to how to fully close a graphical Qt program?  Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things that could possible solve your problem:

1. Before displaying the *messagebox*, stop the timer with the *stop()* method.
2. After the *QApplication::quit();* exit the function with *return;* Your function might be running to the end one last time and accessing invalid objects.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else's reference Rafael Monteiro's answer was spot on.  Here is the updated code (verified working):

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void frmMain::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *) {
    if(qtimer->isActive()) qtimer->stop();      // had to stop timer here !!!!!!!!
    QApplication::quit();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void frmMain::processFrameAndUpdateGUI() {
    bool blnFrameReadSuccessfully = capWebcam.read(matOriginal);                    // get next frame from the webcam

    if (!blnFrameReadSuccessfully || matOriginal.empty()) {                            // if we did not get a frame
        QMessageBox::information(this, "", "unable to read from webcam \n\n exiting program\n");
        closeEvent(new QCloseEvent());
        return;          // had to add return here !!!!!!!!!
    }

    // rest of function here . . .
```

I should mention I had to add both the return and stop the timer.  Thanks Rafael!

Comment: This looks a little hacky and ugly. You shouldn't call `closeEvent` directly. It's an event handler. Instead you should call [`QWidget::close`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#close). You could also try using the [`QApplication::closeAllWindows`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#closeAllWindows) slot.